# Using Angular promises with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have an Angular SPA, which loads a bunch of data from the backend and displays them in, let's say tables. In order to provide a better user experience, I'm hiding those tables while the data is loaded and display a spinner. So I end up writing code like this:

**Template:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <spinner ng-show="ctrl.loading.unicorns"></spinner>
    <ul ng-hide="ctrl.loading.unicorns">
      <li ng-repeat="unicorn in ctrl.unicorns">{{ unicorn.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function unicornController() {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.loading = {
    unicorns: true
  };

  unicornService
    .get()
    .then(function(data) {
      ctrl.unicorns = data;
    })
    .finally(function() {
      ctrl.loading.unicorns = false;
    });

  return ctrl;
}
```

With one loader it's not a big deal, but when I have 3 of them in every view, it feels like the loading could be handled in a better way. I found out that promises have a `$$state.status` property which holds exactly this value, but afaik I should not use that as it's not part of the public API. Is there any other way to achieve this without messing around local flags?

Comment: Do you want it to wait for all the loaders before showing the data?

Comment: I'd rather show them one by one. I think that's better because the user will actually see that something is happening

Comment: You can check ctrl.unicorns != null instead of declare new ctrl.loading scope var, or use something like $("#mySpinnerDiv").show() in unicornService implementation.
Again, add a cssclass on unicornList container and $(".unicornList").append("<spinner></spinner>") in unicornService implementation and its remove in finally.

Comment: @Frix33 Yes I could check for null values, but what if I need to reload the data for some reason? Btw I'd rather not mix Angular code with jQuery.

Comment: for reload data you need to empty ctrl.unicorns before call unicornService. In angular you also can implement a directive my-loader="ctrl.unicorns" can inject spinner  in your parent <div>,  and check if (my-loader-var(ctrl.unicorns)).loading is true. All service have to add .loading property at start of invocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can either find a way to do it yourself or you can find an existing way to do it.

Here is a usefull projects that will automatically display the progress of your `$http` requests.

[Angular loading bar](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

*Install (npm or bower)*

```
$ npm install angular-loading-bar
$ bower install angular-loading-bar
```

*Include*

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it a lot and you need to have independent loader maybe it is good idea to implement specific directive/component just for that?

Simple example with [spinKit](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) spinner.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').component('loading', {
  transclude: true,
  template: `
    <div class="spinner" ng-show="$ctrl.loading"></div>
    <ng-transclude ng-hide="$ctrl.loading"></ng-transclud>
  `,
  bindings: {
    promise: '<'
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.loading = false;

    this.$onChanges = function() {
      if (this.promise != null) {
        this.loading = true;
        this.promise
          .then(function() {
            this.loading = false;
          }.bind(this));
      }
    }.bind(this);
  }
});

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function($timeout) {
  this.emitPromise = function(propName) {
    this[propName] = createRandomPromise()
      .then(function(result) {
        this[propName + 'Result'] = result;
      }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this);

  function createRandomPromise() {
    var time = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000); // up to 3s

    return $timeout(function() {
      return time;
    }, time);
  }
});
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 10px auto;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
  }
}
@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  <loading promise="Ex.x">
    x result = {{Ex.xResult}}
  </loading>
  <br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Ex.emitPromise('x')">emit x</button>
  <br>
  <loading promise="Ex.y">
    y result = {{Ex.yResult}}
  </loading>
  <br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Ex.emitPromise('y')">emit y</button>
</div>
```

Or if you wish you can use directive to insert result to transcluded scope:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').directive('loading', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    template: `
      <div class="spinner" ng-show="loading"></div>
      <div class="target" ng-hide="loading"></div>
    `,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl, $transclude) {
      $scope.loading = false;
      
      var targetElem = angular.element($element[0].querySelector('.target'));

      $scope.$watch(watchFn, function(promise) {
        if (promise != null) {
          $scope.loading = true;
          promise.then(function(result) {
              $scope.loading = false;
              $scope.result = result;
            
              $transclude($scope, function (content) {
                targetElem.empty();
                targetElem.append(content);
              });
            });
        }
      });
      
      function watchFn() {
        return $parse($attrs.promise)($scope);
      }
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function($timeout) {
  this.parentValue = 'parent Value';
  
  this.emitPromise = function(propName) {
    this[propName] = createRandomPromise();
  }.bind(this);

  function createRandomPromise() {
    var time = Math.round(Math.random() * 3000); // up to 3s

    return $timeout(function() {
      return time;
    }, time);
  }
});
```

```css
.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 10px auto;
  -webkit-animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-rotateplane 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px)
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg)
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateY(180deg) rotateX(180deg)
  }
}
@keyframes sk-rotateplane {
  0% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180.1deg) rotateY(0deg)
  }
  100% {
    transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(120px) rotateX(-180deg) rotateY(-179.9deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  <loading promise="Ex.x">
    x result = {{result}}
  </loading>
  <br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Ex.emitPromise('x')">emit x</button>
  <br>
  <loading promise="Ex.y">
    y result = {{result}}<br>
    Ex.parentValue = {{Ex.parentValue}}
  </loading>
  <br>
  <button type="button" ng-click="Ex.emitPromise('y')">emit y</button>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah, I had something similar to this. My issue with this is that it's not really a flexible solution as Bootstrap often requires direct parent-child relation, and introducing a directive will result a directive element and an ng-transclude element in-between. And it doesn't eliminate the need for the loading flag either. I'd rather stick with the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` on the same level

Comment: @fodma1 well, this does move problem of loading flag to directive, so it is easier, as for parent/child problem... That happens a lot with angular. Maybe try using attribute directive?